# Where can I get Blender test builds?

Tags: versions

I know that [Blender.org](http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/) provides downloads for official releases. I see on forums that people use newer versions of Blender. Where can I get newer version of Blender (nightly builds, alpha versions... etc).

Comment: Also.. for windows- http://www.miikahweb.com/en/blender/builds

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get daily builds for Linux, Windows and Mac from [graphicall.org](http://GraphicAll.org). Here you can also find GSOC and custom builds (Yafaray, Luxrender support etc).

Answer (score 19):

## GIT/Development builds:

- **[The Buildbot:](http://builder.blender.org/download/)**
  There is a [buildbot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buildbot) that builds from the [git repo](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/) daily. You can get git (development) builds for all operating systems that blender supports [here](http://builder.blender.org/download/).
- **Compile from source:**
  Another option is compiling blender from source, see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender). *While this may seem like a lot of effort, once its setup, it can be less trouble then having to continually download large files, and you can test new features minutes after they're committed.*

## Release candidates:

You can get past releases and current test-builds/release candidates [here](http://download.blender.org/release/).

## Linux:

There are some additional options for linux besides GraphicAll.org and the ones listed above.

- **Ubuntu:**
  You can use a [PPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive) such as the [irie PPA](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender). (See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/169546/183331) on AskUbuntu for instructions)
- **Archlinux:**
  The `blender-git` package in the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/blender-git/)

Comment: I like your answer, but the other guy had the website that I was looking for. Also Archlinux?? are you crazy I can't do that ;-)

Comment: @BlenderBoy You could also use the [buildbot](http://builder.blender.org/download/), you don't have to use Arch.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get official daily builds here https://builder.blender.org/download/