# Can't find the Modifier section in Strip properties to use curves

Tags: modifiers, video-sequence-editor

I am using Blender to do video editing, for most part it has been great.

I have been using these tutorials :

As you can see from the video there seems to be Modifier section in properties of the strip modifier. 
http://youtu.be/9hR2zNBxh68?t=50s
And this one

http://www.blendtuts.com/video_editing   (if you jump to 20 mins)

But on mine there is no section like that, I am using Blender 2.62 on Ubuntu 12.04

Is there a way to enable this modifiers section.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried a newer build of Blender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why is simple, this feature is not in Blender 2.62. I wasn't able to find the exact version it was added but looking at the videos. I would say any version 2.68 or higher will have strip modifiers.

Comment: This feature was [added as a part of GSoC 2011](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2012-September/049700.html) it seems, documentation is scarce and I couldn't find anything in the release logs. This is all trivial anyway, just grab an updated build and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks what were people using to adjust brightness and contrast in the older releases

Answer (score 2):

As [iKlsR said](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5179/599), this feature is not in 2.62.

To do this kind of manipulation with 2.62 you will need to use the [*Compositor*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/introduction.html#introduction).
You can adjust the brightness/contrast in the compositor with a [*BrightContrast*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/bright_contrast.html#bright-contrast-node) node or an [*RGB Curves*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/rgb_curves.html#rgb-curves-node) node.

## However, I would *highly* recommend updating your version of blender.
Updating blender:

For Ubuntu, you can install up to date versions of blender by using the [irie PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eirie/+archive/blender). Add the PPA to your sources with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
sudo apt-get update
```

See [this post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/169542/183331) for more details.

You can also use portable versions from [blender.org](http://www.blender.org/download/):

1. Download the tarball and extract
2. Run the `blender` executable in the extracted directory to run blender
3. (Optional) create a launcher `.desktop` file, see [this post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher) for more information.

Note that you can have multiple portable versions of blender at one time.

---

Also see [Where can I get Blender test builds?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/where-can-i-get-blender-test-builds)