# No bevel option in 2.62

Tags: linux, versions

I'm trying to bevel an object, but I can't see any option for that. I've tried using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> shortcut and *Mesh > Edges > Bevel*. But as it can be seen in the screenshot, there is no option for that.

I'm using Blender 2.62 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm not sure, but I think I downloaded Blender from the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

Comment: Does `Ctrl-B` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mentioned by iKlsR](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5730/599), this feature is not in 2.62. However, there is a workaround:

1. Select the edges which you want to bevel and set the *Bevel Weight* to `1`:

   [image]
2. Add a bevel modifier and set the *Limit Method* to *Weight*:

   [image]
3. If you want more bevel segments, duplicate the modifier by pressing *Copy*, then adjust the *Width* of the new modifier:

   [image]

Note that I **strongly** recommend updating your version of blender instead.

From my [previous answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5182/599):

> ## Updating blender:
>
> For Ubuntu, you can install up to date versions of blender by using the [irie PPA](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender). Add the PPA to your sources with:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> See [this post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/169542/183331) for more details.
>
> You can also use portable versions from [blender.org](http://www.blender.org/download/):
>
> 1. Download the tarball and extract
> 2. Run the `blender` executable in the extracted directory to run blender
> 3. (Optional) create a launcher `.desktop` file. See [this post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher) for more information.
>
> Note that you can have multiple portable versions of blender at one
>   time.
>
> ---
>
> Also see [Where can I get Blender test builds?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/where-can-i-get-blender-test-builds)

Comment: Oh, didn't realized my blender version was outdated. Thank you so much for the answer. Both you and iKIsR were really helpful, but I'm picking yours as the answer for the workaround. Thanks a lot, you two!

Just a quick question, now that I have the PPA added, will updates come through the Update Manager or I'll have to download them manually?

Comment: @Gus If you have re-installed blender from the PPA by running `sudo apt-get install blender` after adding the PPA to your sources, it should update automatically. For more about PPAs see [this post on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/4983/183331).

Comment: Yes, I did that. Once again, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The bevel feature in question wasn't added until [Blender 2.63](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh#Bevel) and shortcuts weren't added until [2.64](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.64/BMesh#Misc) so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> won't work.

Comment: Also see [Is there a PPA for the latest Blender version?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4586/is-there-a-ppa-for-the-latest-blender-version).