# no module called numpy

Tags: python, scripting

I hit `Shift+F4` to get the Blender Python console.

```
   PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE 3.2.3 (default, Sep 25 2013, 19:38:45)  [GCC 4.7.2]

>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

On the web, I found some instructions that might work, that involved copying my Python3 numpy into the Blender Folder.  http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?217270-How-to-install-numpy

1. Install python3.2
2. Install numpy for python3.2 using the python3.2 command instead of python
3. on my system numpy was located in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages. Copy numpy from there to blender/2.57/scripts/modules

Looking around and with help from [StackOverflow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144766/where-does-blender-install-on-ubuntu) In my case, copied numPy to `/usr/lib/blender/modules` however it still cannot find.

I may have done some of these steps wrong or not represented them accurately. This is to the best of my memory.

Comment: Are you using blender 2.57? If you are not, try copying it to `blender/$version/scripts/modules` instead.

Comment: While you need to get the blender version right you also want to use a matching python version. python 3.2 was used up until blender 2.64 - I expect you have a blender version higher than 2.64 so you will want to use a python 3.3 module.

Comment: I noticed in your other question that you are using 2.63 you may want to install a newer version as 2.63 is 19 months old and there has been a lot of python changes since 2.63 so you may find it hard to get help writing python for the older versions - the current release is 2.69

Comment: @sambler I got the most current Python and Blender I could find.  Now I can run my `numpy` script finally.

Comment: @johnmangual Have a read of [Where can I get Blender test builds](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/where-can-i-get-blender-test-builds/3439#3439)

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the `numpy` installation (or any other Python package) into:

`..\Blender\2.69\python\lib\site-packages\`

it works with no problem.

---

**Practice:** go to the above directory and create a sub-directory `these`. Go inside `these` and create a empty file `__init__.py`.

In `Python` console inside `Blender` now if you type: `import these` it works like a charm. This is the same story for any other package.

Answer (score 0):

@Sambler

I installed Python 3.3 with `sudo apt-get install python3.3`

Then I installed pip from http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html calling `python3.3` instead of `python`.  This required getting `python3.3-dev` with `apt-get`

Installing numPy was straightforward after this `pip-3.3 install numpy`

Finally I installed blender from http://www.blender.org/download/ and unzip with `tar jxvf blender-2.69-linux-glibc211-x86_64.tar.bz2` and now it runs with `./blender`

I added this line to `~/.bashrc`: `export PATH="/path/to/blender:$PATH"`