# Walk Mode in 2.69?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm using Blender 2.69, and having tried the Fly Mode and finding it wasn't to my liking, I started looking to see if there was a preferable alternative.

I found this:
https://developer.blender.org/D30
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View/Navigation_Modes

However, in my UI in blender, I don't see a "view" option at the top of the screen, nor under File > User Preferences > Input do I see anything allowing me to change the view navigation mode. In fact, searching in Input for "view", "navigation", "fly", "walk", and other searches only gave me hotkey bindings to enable/disable Fly Mode, and to change the key bindings for it, neither of which are what I want.

It's clear that the Walk Mode does exist, the question is: is this some kind of experimental new version of Blender I need to download/build manually? Is this an older feature that's long since been removed? or is my UI mis-configured, or is this a plugin?

I've seen other people asking for a feature like this, and the answer they were always given is "doesn't exist". If you can help me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a version *newer* than 2.69, try installing/building a development version. (see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599))

Once you have a version of blender from after the [commit you linked to](https://developer.blender.org/rBab494379586034a6844c858324815e3b1ff3cbb2) (Dec 2 2013), *Walk mode* should be the default. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> in the *3D view* to activate it.

You can change the navigation mode settings in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User preferences > Input > View Navigation*:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. In case anyone wonders, this is the version I used. Installation consisted of unzipping a folder, and nothing more.

http://graphicall.org/110