# Does a game engine runtime work on all operating systems?

Tags: game-engine

Do game engine runtimes work on all versions of windows? Would it work on Linux and OSX too?  I am assuming it only works on Windows but I would like to know for sure.

Also, would it be possible to burn it to a disc?

Answer (score 5):

No, the output is dependent on the OS that you called it from ([Blender 2.6 Doc](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/FAQ/Game_Engine/Standalone_game))

If you executed make runtime on Windows, then the output is a Windows executable (and various DLL files). This package will only work on Windows.

Running the same function on the Mac will give you a Mac .app file, etc.

Comment: This is weird because before I asked this question I went on Linux and made a runtime from blender while using Linux and Linux could not open it.  Than I thought that it would only work on Windows so I put it on a flash drive and tried to open it on Windows but of course it did not.

Comment: @FatBunny was the file marked as executable?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [new addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Game_Engine/Publishing) being developed (it's already included in master, so it is bundled with the [latest builds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599)) which allows creation of runtimes for multiple platforms.

From the [official developer blog](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2014/06/new-game-engine-publishing-addon/):

> One of the common complaints with the Blender Game Engine is with
>   publishing games. While there are many issues related to publishing
>   with the BGE, one issue is the lack of a simple, user-friendly way to
>   publish to multiple platforms. Steps are being taken to resolve this
>   with a new Game Engine Publishing addon that has been recently
>   committed to master (should be available in buildbot builds by now).
>   This addon is intended to replace the old Save As Runtime addon, and
>   currently provides the following improvements:
>
> - New panel in the Render Properties to control publishing (this also means publishing options are saved in the blend file)
> - Easier cross-platform publishing (this requires downloading the binaries for the desired platforms, see the [addon’s wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Game_Engine/Publishing) page for more
>     information)
> - Ability to create archives (e.g., tarballs and zips) for published games
> - Ability to automatically copy extra game files (e.g., scripts, unpacked textures, logic, other blend files, etc.) when publishing