# Save single FireSim Frame

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

I am currently running Blender 2.82.7 and made a fire simulation in one .blend file, which I need to carry over to another .blend file, which will be rendered as a still image, so no animation over there.
Question is:
I now have a good looking frame for the fire, is there any way I can preserve this specific stage of fire simulation forever, so I can take it around and place it wherever I wish, without having to worry of it still being a running simulation?

Thanks for reading. Stay healthy :)

Comment: it seems it's not possible: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/is-it-possible-to-bake-a-single-frame-of-a-smoke-simulation?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link, I totally missed that.

Comment: If you don't mind, please either create and accept an answer, or accept the answer I have provided so this is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bake only up to the desired frame, that is the easiest solution.

As referenced in the comments, this [does not appear to be possible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/is-it-possible-to-bake-a-single-frame-of-a-smoke-simulation?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

You can bake the simulation on the original file.

Then import or link the objects to the second project and re-link the simulation cache.

The simulation cache is in a folder called data (usually in the same directory as the .blend file), inside the folder there are a bunch of files with a number, each one of those file has the fire simulation for a frame of the animation. Just look for the one you need.

You could even copy the contents of the simulation cache for the frame you want, to all of the other frames by making copies of the cache file and renaming them with different frame numbers.