# How would I make a cloudy backdrop in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm attempting to recreate a scene with a cloudy backdrop from blender render to cycles.

I have a metaball which I've applied the cloud tool on to make good looking clouds and have set a plane with transparency and a cloud texture, on top of that the world color is a color which compliments the other colors in the scene.

I am unsure as to how I would go about converting this to cycles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44941/is-there-an-easy-way-to-make-volumetric-clouds-for-cycles and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/how-to-create-and-render-clouds-in-blender-cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want, your best option may be to just make a procedural sky.  Here is a great tutorial for that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr6wTyfAO04  Making the clouds procedural will save you a ton on render times.  Although, if you are trying to fly through the clouds, they would need to be more volumetric and realistic.  Here is a great tutorial by BlenderGuru just for that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJ_OcBh7F5I

To make a simple cloud all you really need to do is connect a Volume Scatter node to your materials volume input.

[image]

You can raise the density for a more stormy look.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! I could find tutorials and ways to make the clouds themselves but I couldnt find the way to make the sky that way as well, thanks for that.

Comment: add some noise texture to the Density and a bit of variation to the color to fake detail within the volume. this way your model can stay quite simple.

Comment: @CyberBurst please help us to bring up the quality of this site. Pointing to links in external sites might help to answer the question, but consider adding more detail so that your answer stands on its own besides the links.