# (static) volumetric cloud?

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I want to render some volumetric clouds to fly an airplane around. I don't need them to be animated, and would prefer them to be static to save render time. So I just need one frame of the simulation for the whole animation. How would be a good way to do this with the smoke simulator? Like is there a way to save a frame of the smoke to a file and load it back in?

Comment: Of course, if there is no interaction, I'd suggest [**create clouds**](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/how-to-create-and-render-clouds-in-blender-cycles/7755#7755) in different sizes, render and save them as seperate exr's. Then 'load them back in' by using the [compositor](https://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/index.html).

Comment: Great! Odd though. How can you load 3d data into a 2d frame and have it at right "angle".

Comment: By using [**images as planes addon**](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27635/3710) which is shipped with blender by default, you can easily arange your 'image clouds' in the main scene.

Comment: That won't work, if all I'll get will be a texture on a billboard. I want the clouds to looks 3d when flying around them, Not turning and facing the camera

Comment: Depends on the shot. If the camera's angle is too heavy the 'image clouds' are noticeable of course, but for lower angles this works fine.

Comment: Well won't work for me. I need volumes, just "static" ones.