# Making holes in a mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How do I make a hole in an object?

[image: I need to put a hole in the selected face.]

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me exactly what you're asking. Is this for use in a game situation, or in an animated film? My first impression is that you want the (moving) pick head to create a hole in the tube object during an animated sequence. If that's not what you intend, perhaps you can edit your question to make things clearer.

Comment: Watch this video: http://www.blendernation.com/2013/07/14/8-methods-of-cutting-holes/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You could use a couple different methods:

## [Boolean modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html):

1. Add a boolean modifier on the object you want to cut a hole in,
2. Create an object to "subtract" from the main object
3. Set that object in the boolean modifier. You can press <kbd>E</kbd> while hovering over the object selection field to set the field by clicking on an object in the 3D view.

[image]

## [knife project tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html#knife-project):

1. Add a circle or some other object to define the outline of the hole
2. With the circle selected, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the object you want to cut a hole in and enter edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)
3. Select the faces you want to cut, then click *knife project* in the *tool shelf*. If you want to cut all the way through the mesh, enable *Cut through* in the redo panel (<kbd>F6</kbd>)
4. Then select the newly cut edges with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and press <kbd>W</kbd>*> Bridge edge loops* to connect the ends of the hole.

[image]

## [Face intersect tool:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#intersect)

*This feature will be [added in 2.72](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Modeling/), but until then you can use it in the [latest development builds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599).*

This is essentially like the boolean modifier, except it works in edit mode.

[image]

<sub>[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rwvxusuJXU&feature=youtu.be&hd=1) is a nice video made by the author of this feature, explaining how it works.</sub>

Comment: It seems like your reputation has gone up 20,000k in just a few months... that amuses me.

Comment: @gandalf3 +1 Never new about the intersect tool!

Comment: @gandalf3 I try to understand your booelan method. But I don't understand what you mean with "You can press E while hovering over the object selection field to set the field by clicking on an object in the 3D view." ??

Comment: @JanScherders By "object selection field" I was referring to the place were the *Cylinder* object is specified in the boolean modifier. You don't have to specify the object by pressing E, but with many objects in can be easier.

Comment: I thought "E" was for extrusion ?

Comment: @JanScherders In edit mode yes, but this is in the panel. Here's gif: http://pasteall.org/pic/93475. There's now a little eye-dropper icon which you can click to get the same effect (this answer was written before that was added).

Comment: For the knife, on point 1 the cutting object has to be a manifold one (has no face). For instance it cannot be the wood part. Worked for me: Select the cutting object > Edit mode > 'a' (select everything) > 'x' (delete) > Remove only faces. Then use it with Knife Projection

Answer (score 0):

For 2.8 join the two object together then in *Edit Mode* select the object you want to make the cut (hover object and press <kbd>L</kbd> ) *Face Menu > Intersect*, should be half way down the menu

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'join the two objects together'?

Answer (score 0):

As of Blender 3.5.1:

Punching holes in Objects:
In Object mode, Select hole shape object and move into place on main object.
[image][image]
Select Main object.
Add Modifier (wrench icon) - Hit Down arrow/Generate/Boolean/Difference.
[image]
Select little square next to where it says Object.
[image]
Choose mesh for cutting hole.
Click Down arrow on Boolean line.
Apply.
[image]
Select punched object (G) and move out of hole.
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can also use curves for modelling the base mesh.then use the curve with edit mode then add a bezier circle to make a hole.

Comment: Sorry for bumping, but those steps are indescriptive, unclear, and mainly **wrong**. Fix them. Where on Earth would adding a Bézier circle create a hole instead of just adding.... a circle? :P