# Boolean within the same object?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

The boolean modifier works on separate objects. But is there a way to boolean together multiple pieces of mesh within the same object?

Intersect faces leaves too much messy geometry.

Comment: Not non-destructively no. But if you just want a one-off operation, then yes. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15688/599, in particular the *Face Intersect* tool.

Comment: It may work, depending on how it works. I'm trying to find better options than the Intersect tool under Faces, as that leaves messy internal geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying *Boolean Union* to all islands within an object's mesh in a non-destructive way is very easy since the introduction of *Geometry Nodes*. Just apply *Mesh Boolean* node to the geometry.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would try.

In object mode, make one copy of your original object for each separate part of the original object you want to use as a boolean operator with the original. If the object you want to boolean with itself has more than one mesh sub object, switch to edit mode, select each individual sub-object  containing portions you want to use as boolean operators, use the duplicate tool (<kbd>SHFT</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>) to make a copy of the sub-object, and then separate the duplicate of the sub-object into a new object using the <kbd>P</kbd> key, choosing the "Selection" option.

You will now have an original and one or more copies of the original, or portions of it. On one of the copies, select the parts of the mesh you want to use to operate on the original, perform the boolean operation, and then delete the copy. Repeat this for each part of the object that you want to use in a boolean operation. When completed you will have effectively used the object to perform the boolean with itself, and yet Blender will be satisfied that you are doing the operation between different objects.