# How to create a complex shape for 3d printing with holes using a single mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, boolean-modifier

Hello I'm new to Blender, but I'm learning fast. I'm attempting to recreate this for 3D printing:
[image]
It's a present for Christmas.

I followed this youtube video tutorial: [Turn Any 2D Image to 3D Model - Quick & Easy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcjPCjxsCZo). I added a plane and applied an image as a texture to get the initial shape.

Now I have a pretty good starting mesh:
[image: Starting Mesh]

I'm trying to remove the spaces that have been marked with edges to extrude the shape I'm going for. I've tried the solutions in this question: [Boolean within the same object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35537/boolean-within-the-same-object). I've tried a Geometry Node using Mesh Boolean and creating duplicate sub-objects and using the boolean modifier to subtract the space. The former ends with odd results and the latter doesn't work at all.

Here is the result of using the Mesh Boolean Geometry Node:[image: Mesh Boolean Geometry Node]

Can anyone offer guidance on removing the 4 spaces seen in the first image?

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: Use Delete > Limited Disolve. Convert Mesh to Curve, under curve properties switch curve from 3D to 2D, Fill Mode > Both, than you can set Geometry > Extrude, Bevel (use Depth value in Offset, but in negative value) ... when you are fine with result convert to Mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Delete > Limited Disolve. You dont need so many points.

[image]

Convert Mesh to Curve, under curve properties switch curve from 3D to 2D, Fill Mode > Both ...

[image]

than you can set Geometry > Extrude, Bevel (use Depth value in Offset, but in negative value) ...

[image]

when you are fine with result convert to Mesh.

---

BTW ... note to your tutorial you follow ... there is much straight forward way :) Just drag&drop your black&white image into 3Dviewport and search for **Trace Image to Grease Pencil** ... than search **Convert Grease Pencil > Bezier Curve** (don't use *Convert to* operator that is not mean to be be for GP, this still confuse me). Now just set mentioned curve properties.