# How do you embed one object in another?

Tags: modeling

I'm using Blender 2.76, with Cycles renderer.

I'd like to build a model of a thin opaque plate with glass beads embedded in it, with light shining through the glass. I know how to create the plate, the light, and the glass pieces. What functions should I look into as a way to put the glass in the plate so the hole exactly fits the glass?

Here's an image of the pieces. I duplicated the glass piece and simply moved it to coincide with the opaque plate.

[image]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/making-holes-in-a-mesh/15688#15688

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I guess this should be marked duplicate or deleted?