# Negative cylander

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a key chain and using blender to model it but I made they object but I can't figure out how to make a cylindrical hole at the top of the object.

Comment: You should look at this; https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/making-holes-in-a-mesh

Comment: watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you cut a shape out of an object using another object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object)

Comment: And please for the love of god don't go down the boolean road

Answer (score 0):

Use a Boolean modifier with "difference" selected and the object as the cylindrical shape you want to cut out.

[Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) is some documentation on Boolean modifiers.

The problem with booleans is the ugly geometry left behind. If you want a bit more control when creating a hole in something, you can use the knife (k) tool to draw an outline for the hole. If you are creating a hole in a closed volume, you can connect the two holes made with the knife using the bridge edge loops tool.

[Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html) for knife tool and [Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops) for bridge edge loop