# Embedding vertices onto a plane

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

Say that I have a collection of points, as shown below with the circle, and I have a plane that I want to merge them onto. The points and plane are perfectly parallel, and the end goal is that the plane I'm merging onto doesn't move. Is there a way to do this? I think it could be done in a roundabout way with a boolean modifier, but there must be a better way.

[image: Points on a plane]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/making-holes-in-a-mesh/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve