# How do I make knife cuts into a mesh *based* on another mesh? (Not boolean)

Tags: mesh

So I have this (selected plane in edit mode below) plane and I want to cut into it with this mesh (the mesh on top):
[image]

The crucial bit is that I'm *not* looking to use the boolean mod to punch out a shape. I just want the curve of this long, thin piece to be part of the plane's geometry. That way, I can select those faces and adjust the Z location (riverbed).

I've tried using the boolean modifiers but have had no luck. Is there a way for me to project this other mesh *onto* the plane?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you looking for a knife project? Just used one here in a recent answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194314/19156 or in the docs https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77279

Comment: Thanks you two! This was yet another case of "I didn't know the proper term for what I wanted to do." Appreciate the help! Worked like a charm.