# How can you use one object to delete the same 3d space on another object?

Tags: text-object

[image]

Hello!
I made a 3D logo a couple years ago and want to update to how it should've been made in the first place. I want to take the logo on the left and make it like the logo on the right. Does anyone know the best way to do that?

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use a **Boolean Modifier** set to _Intersect_

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/making-holes-in-a-mesh

Answer (score 1):

As Christopher Bennett says, if you use *Boolean* modifier / *Intersect* mode it will work fine:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That helped so much! Took just 5 minutes instead of 5 hours the wrong way haha.