# How do I add a circle into my house wall?

Tags: modeling, texturing, objects, vertices

[image]

hello, so I've build this house and I want to add a round window below the roof. Kind of reached a bottleneck here and don't know what to do, youtube tutorials aren't very helpful.. What should I do in order to accomplish that red circle into my wall. It can't be added with the circle tool because I want to use "E"-Key inward to give it a window effect, so it must be drawn onto the wall. Thx for replies!

Comment: Destructive way is to use knife project. Quick and dirty.

Comment: Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/making-holes-in-a-mesh, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object

Answer (score 3):

There are a few approaches to this.  I'm going to describe the non-destructive *Boolean* workflow.

- Create a cylinder matching the radius of your circle and rotate it so it is perpendicular to the wall.
- Position it so that is passes through the wall where you want the circle.
- Go to its Object properties and under Viewport Display change "Display As" to wire.

[image: Object Data Properties showing Display as Dropdown about to select wire]

You have just created what is called a *cutter*.  Next the cutter is applied to create the hole:

- In object mode, select the object that has your wall in it and add a Boolean modifier
- Make sure its type is set to *Difference*
- Select the cylinder as the *Object* (I named my cylinder "cutter")
- You may have to change the Solver to *Fast*

[image: Boolean modifier set to difference]

You should end up with something that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

another way to do this:

1. if you have subdivided your wall, select 9 vertices like this:

[image]

2. mesh -> transform to sphere or Shift - Alt-S 1

[image]

3. do the same on the other side and select both "circles"

then

[image]

result:

[image]

Hint: the more subdivisions you had before, the rounder the hole will be.

Answer (score 2):

Select the face where you want to have your hole:

[image]

subdivide it

[image]

Mesh -> Transform to Sphere -> Drag your mouse

[image]

Correct with S -> Y

[image]

Now tap your "E" and you got:

[image]