Blender Select Faces Hollow


Hi! I am new to Blender and I'm trying to build my first object, a washing-machine. I am trying to hollow out just the drum of the washer, but when I removed the front face of the cylinder, the front face of the washer is still there. I added 2 photos for reference to my question, how can I do a face-select on just the blue part I have scribbled over so I can remove just that face? Thanks in advance!
I tried right-clicking and trying "subdivide", "split", "separate". I also tried watching multiple tutorials. I tried the knife feature to cut out the circle. I'm at a loss!

Hello and welcome. Making holes in a mesh has been asked before: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/making-holes-in-a-mesh. Here are other methods https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0wyTP_Doxw. Then please read Holes in Faces for more information

As far as I understand, you want to make a round hole for the drum in this place? You can add a new cylinder object, so that it is rotated in the direction you need, creating a round drum, and then select the cylinder and your washing machine, apply the boolean modifier (hotkey ctrl + numpad -). This way you get the hole you need and can make a frame around it

That key combination will only work if you have the built-in Bool Tool addon activated in Preferences > Addons.

Oh, Yes, thanks
