Create a square hole on a wall
I created a wall in blender using a plane and extrude options. I had coordinates for 4 vertices to make the plane. I used those measurements to make the wall.Now I want to cut a rectangle on the wall so, that it will look like a door. I have specific coordinates to make the hole. The four vertices has four co ordinates. I need to use those co ordinates to make the hole. So my main concern is to cut the wall depending upon the co ordinate.
How can I do that?

This is super easy, but I wanna try and let someone else answer. If nobody can help you in time, ping me.

@TheLabCat, please let me know. I didn't understand how to do it? I saw tutorials on loopcut, knife, but did not find the way

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object/34460#34460 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/making-holes-in-a-mesh/15688#15688
