# How to Create an Sci Fi "Plasma/Energetic/Force Field" Material in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Hello mates im in Search of the answer to how to create a Material that looks like sci fi energetic/plasma/force field  in Cycles.

Here some Pictures of what i mean in general

[image: Perfect example of what i mean look at that door screen taken from marvel heroes 2015]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/31984/14863

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could try a setup like this:

[image]

[image]

If you animate some of the mapping nodes, you can get an effect like this:

[image]

The essentially part of the rather largish setup above is in the screenshot below.
The only difference between the nodes below and the largish shader is that the latter has a texture controlling the intensity/color of the emission shader.

[image]

These nodes mix an emission shader with a transparent shader based on the angle of the surface to the camera (details [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/31984/14863)). It also makes backfaces (faces facing away from the camera) transparent.

The large setup has a mixture of procedural textures controlling multiple emission shaders which are added together in place of the single emission shader in the setup above.
Of course, you can use any texture setup you want, even image textures.

Making a hexagonal procedural texture will probably be tricky with the current selection of procedural textures available in cycles, so you are probably best off either making the object's topology in the shape of hexagons, or using an image texture.

---

Note that if you have a more complex object in place of a sphere, skipping backfaces might not be enough to avoid rendering faces not directly visible to the camera.

By using the setup from my answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/31984/14863), this can be made to work on more complex objects:

> To get rid of the geometry behind the rest of the model, you can use
> the *Transparent depth* output of the lightpath node (note that this
> output is only available in the [latest development versions of
> blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599), but it will be
> in 2.71)
>
> This value goes up based on the number of "transparent bounces" (a
> transparent bounce refers to the sampling ray passing through a
> transparent layer/surface of the mesh). Since we only want to see the
> top layer, we can use a *Less than* math node and a *mix shader* node
> to make every bounce past the first bounce (bounce 0) will use only
> the completely transparent shader (*Transparent Depth* is never
> negative, so this is basically testing if it's equal to 0).
>
> [image]

For comparison here is a gif demonstrating the difference between only hiding backfaces and hiding all faces invisible to the camera:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is looking verry good but it surely would be better if i would understand that Nodetree so i can adjust it to my belongings. What i had in Mind is exact this same Blue Shield but with a Octanogonal Pattern (Honeycomb) but altleast i have a approach now ^^

Comment: @TheCycleOfBlend Working on it ;) My answer on gd.se is a bit more detailed atm, but I'll finish editing this in a bit.

Comment: I started with this: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?277291-Cycles-Plasma but your nodes are awesome.

Comment: What's with the RGB dropdown on your color ramps? Is that a new feature?

Comment: Where do I nominate this to the Node's hall of fame?

Comment: @ajwood Yes, It'll be in 2.72. Now you can switch between RGB, HSV, and HSL interpolation.

Comment: @TheCycleOfBlend Edited

Comment: thanks for that by the way look up i found the perfect image refrence of what i was talking about

Comment: Hi @gandalf3, the link for the example is expired. Could you update it? We tried your setup but didn't really get it.