# Cycles support for gtx 1070

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I just got my MSI gtx 1070 gaming X card today and tried to render something in cycles but to my surprise I got this message.
[image]

Is Pascal still not supported? Are there anyways around this/fix it? 
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: ; ~ ; I thought they would by August, the forums have lied to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initial support for CUDA 8.0 cards has been [added to master](https://developer.blender.org/rB6353ecb996898b4ce2fe8065130ed1f5ea3b6989).
You can download a supported build of blender from the [buildbot](http://builder.blender.org/download/) or [any recent version](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599).

Answer (score 4):

From the [developer meeting notes](https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2016-July/047530.html) (Sunday 31 July 2016):

> Everyone wants the GTX 1080 cards supported with Cycles, unfortunately the required CUDA 8.0 is still not official released. We can add their release candidate though. Sergey Sharybin and Brecht van Lommel check into this."

Proably applies to GTX 1070 too...

Comment: I just used the [latest build (nightly builds?)](https://builder.blender.org/download/) and it works now, not sure if it's faster tho but it works :D