# Expanded List of Themes - Super Light Theme

Tags: theme

Is there an expanded list of Blender Themes hidden in settings anywhere?  I know plugins and themes for many software are hosted on their server to limit the download size.  Yes I know I can download themes myself but that still doesn't give me a list of themes to try.

I prefer a dark text on white background theme but there doesn't seem to be anything close in the 10ish default themes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few more "contrib" themes which aren't included with official releases, but are bundled with [development versions/daily builds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3439/599). You can also download them individually [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/presets/interface_theme/;f178e6c933a25c621a5cc7d92935b66cd2ec2f5d). Currently "white sky" is the only really light theme I'm aware of there.

[image]

Beyond those, there are plenty floating around [on blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/search?q=theme%20category%3A50) among others.

---

To install a theme, drop it in `$BLEND_DIR/scripts/presets/interface_theme` [where `$BLEND_DIR` depends on your platform and how you installed Blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html).

Comment: Link to "contrib" themes no longer works… Any ideas if "white sky" (or similar) theme still exists for actual Blender version / where to download it?

Comment: @ivanzoid I've updated the link, but the themes there haven't been updated to work with 2.8. You can load them and they'll partially work, if you care to fix one or more of them you might see if the devs will take your fixed version and add it back.